# Storing Scanner Input and Using

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a java program, that reads a text file line by line, with each part of the line using a delimiter `:`

The data in text files can be expected to be like:

```
TeamOne : TeamTwo : TeamOneScore : TeamTwoScore.
```

I would like to create a summary, showing how many matches each team has played, and how many goals each have scored.

The data from the text file will likely have multiple instances of the same team, and preferably be able to handle creating a summary if more data is added to the text file.

What would be the best method to store each line of text, so they can be compared?

I would like it to be able to work out if a team **won** or **lost** a game, and the total amount of goals they scored.

Currently, each line is read from the text file, and stored as a string and then split into 4 sections. This all happens within a while loop, and the data is then lost when the next line is read:

```
fileinput = fileread.nextLine(); 
String line = fileinput;
String[] split = line.split(":");
String hometeam = split[0].trim();
String awayteam = split[1].trim();
String home_score = split[2].trim();
String away_score = split[3].trim();
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I doubt there is a single "best method".

Comment: While figuring out the best solution, give it a try to do the simplest possible, which in my opinion is to store each row of data in a list. You should consider reading the file and interpreting the data as two separate tasks.

Comment: I suggest, that you choose *some* method for doing this, implement it, show us what you have, and ask for help if you run into a specific problem or for advice if you think the method you are using can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

So just for your last line: the data is then lost when the next line is read <-- That's clear because you define variables local to the for-loop. So for every iteration the variables will be initialized again. So here is my solution for you:

```
ArrayList<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// open file somewhere
while(fileread.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fileread.nextLine();
    String[] split = line.split(":");
    String[] toAdd = new String[4]
    toAdd[0] = split[0].trim();
    toAdd[1] = split[1].trim();
    toAdd[2] = split[2].trim();
    toAdd[3] = split[3].trim();
    matches.add(toAdd);
}
```

Now you have an ArrayList where each entry is a string array of size 4.
But be aware, if you want to count the total scores, you have to cast the string to an int,
because every attribute of a match is of type string (therefore a string array)

Comment: Thank you!! Will take a look into implementing this, looks like this is exactly what I needed :)